# How to assign attribute points in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Right now it assigns attributes automatically.

Is there any option to assign those myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no ability to assign attribute points. You will always get 3 points in your main stat, 2 in vitality, and 1 in other stats, every level.

Comment: that sucks... those guys had no idea what diablo means... just sad

Comment: I much prefer this system to the old system where you could unknowingly ruin your character, and where the optimal decision was mathematically calculable so there was just needless overhead for the player to consider.

Comment: @StrixVaria That added build strategy to the game, though. Now you can't possibly screw up your character. Admittedly, it's still frustrating to build a character wrong, but it is an extremely easy problem to fix: just add respec points. Median XL Ultimative, the most popular D2 mod which even has its own closed realm, and Path of Exile both implement this feature. Nah, let's not do that, Instead, let's take away agency from the player. It becomes less surprising when you realize that it was developed in the WoW studio instead of now-non-existent Blizzard North.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Paragon points address that.